# How to include "jquery_ujs" with disabled pipeline to be able to use "remote: true" for forms?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm not using assets pipeline. I included a normal jquery file by referring  it as "jquery":

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

How can I do the same thing for "jquery_ujs", what's the proper file name and where can I do it exactly? I want to call a form with `remote: true`. Do that require `jquery_ujs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include asset pipeline to your project, then adding jquery_ujs is required.When using asset pipeline, rails provides half of the javascript required through its helpers.

Now in your case we will have to add the following, either in your application.html or on top of the .html.erb file where you have the form,

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js"></script>
```

Comment: where can I get jquery_ujs?

Comment: the jquery_ujs is loaded from the jquery-rails gem. This is installed default when you create a rails application. You can check for the default assets of jquery-rails here. https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts . When using asset pipeline, the files are loaded from the application.js, Since you don't use asset pipeline, you will have to include the file manually in the pages, where you use forms.

Comment: can't I download it from the source, say from jquery.com or something like that?

Comment: but I haven't found it on jquery.com

Comment: This cannot be downloaded separately, because this is one js created to make Rails work with jQuery. jquery_ujs -> Ruby on Rails unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery. This is the repository where it is hosted. But it is not a single js file as you get jquery.js from jquery.com. Please check the below link https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: You cannot find this in jquery.com. It is an scripting adapter created for Ruby on Rails. I hope this helps.